# @html.dropdownlistfor shows both value and text but has no value set

Tags: linq, dropdownlistfor

I am getting a dictionary from an object:

```
 property.PropertyContacts = db.Users
            .Select(t => new { Value = t.UserId.ToString(), Text = t.LastName + " " + t.FirstName })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Value, t => t.Text);
```

Passing it to the View:

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PropertyContactOverrideValue, new SelectList(Model.PropertyContacts), "-- Select --")
```

But BOTH Value and Text are showing in the text of the DD and nothing is set as value like this: 
[1, Smith Joe]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PropertyContactOverrideValue, new SelectList(Model.PropertyContacts, "Key", "Value"), "-- Select --")
```

needed this...